# R1C1, variable and mathematics in eqation

Tags: excel, vba, variables

Trying to create a a formula from a variable and relative location. 
Variable (X) is a double as well as the cell which RC[1] (isnt set but looks like one) will select

if I run it like this it gives out an application or object defined error.

```
Dim MIDDLEcounter As Integer
Dim Xdatacell As String
Dim Xdatacellvalue As Double
Xdatacell = "B" & MIDDLEcounter (basicly 2 but changable)
Range(Xdatacell).Select
Xdatacellvalue = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1] - " & Xdatacellvalue  & " "
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code aims to do plz

Comment: And maybe [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53125724/edit) to include all relevant parts (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). To begin with where do you set the values for your variables?

Comment: You must assign **MIDDLEcounter** a value before you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something small to see it working. Write only this line:

```
Sub TestMe
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1] - " & "23.8"
End Sub
```

If it works, probably the problem is in the presentation of the `Double` from the local Excel language to VBA:

```
Sub TestMe
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1] - " & Replace("23,8", ",", ".")
End Sub
```

At the end, remove the hardcoded value and give it a try.

Comment: yup that fixed the problem (it was about Excel language to VBA:), thank you!